# MobaXterm disapears from taskbar in Windows 11 after moving window

Tags: taskbar, windows-11, mobaxterm

#### My System:

- Windows 11 Pro (V10.0.22621 Build 22621)
- Dual monitor
- GPU: Nvidia RTX 3080 Ti (mobile) - Driver version (517.00)
- CPU: Intel i9-12900HX
- MobaXterm Version: v23.0 - Build 5042

#### Issues:

There's a few weird issues with MobaXterm that I'm experiencing.

- First, after opening Moba, if I move the Window, it's icon will dissapear from the taskbar (I don't mean tasktray).
  [before moving window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yp8W.png)
  [after moving window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqBp8.png)
- Second, after the icon dissapears from the taskbar, if I try to minimize the window, it just minimizes to a floating window/bar.
  [before minimize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff7DY.png)
  [after minimize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTsSH.jpg)

#### Troubleshooting things I've tried, but didn't work:

- I've tried reinstalling Moba
- I've also tried installing an older version (v22.2)
- I've tried rebooting
- I've tried restoring default settings

Any help with addressing these issues would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you boot into Safe Mode does the same behavior exhbit itself?

Comment: Having same issue

Comment: @Jew, I was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after having spoken with the MobaXterm support team, it was discovered that PowerToys was the culprit. Not sure why exactly, but uninstalling PowerToys resolved the issue. I reinstalled PowerToys and the issue I encountered did not return.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Wow, how did you know that I installed Power Toys yesterday, and How come I forgot that this might be the cause, well programmers are dealing all the time with bugs